# Best allocation for NSString when alternating between constant and non constant strings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsstring

I would like some help better understanding the memory characteristics of Strings in Cocoa.
The app I am working with uses one view controller and n tool objects. The View controller lives for the life of the program but the tool objects are allocated and released.

Suppose I have a string toolName_ and in my implementation I configure the incoming tool object: if the object does not have a tool name, I want to set the toolName_ string to @"not set". If the tool has a name I want to set the string to the name of the tool.

I would like to know the proper way to store the incoming value into the toolName_ given that sometimes this will be an allocated object and sometimes this will be a constant string.

```
-(BOOL)setToolObject: ToolObject: obj{

    ToolObject someObj = nil;
    someObj = [[ToolObject alloc]initWithObject obj];

    if(someObj != nil){

       if(! [someObj.toolName isEqualToString: @""]){

             self->toolName_ = Which method should I use given the above question?
             The last instance may have been a constant string but may not have.
             [self->toolName_ release] (can I send a release message to a constant
             string without causing a problem?) 
             self->toolName = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:someObj.toolName];

              OR

             self->tool name = [NSString stringWithString: someObj.toolName];
             This method is self releasing but I don't own it and I'm still not sure 
             what happens to the constant string if it existed. I think I read it's
             not recommended to use this on member vars.

        }else{

             self->toolName_ = @"not set";
        }

       return YES;           

    }else{

       return NO;
    }

 }
```

Advice appreciated.

Comment: Generally, `self->` is not used to access ivars in Objective-C.   As well, a setter with a return value is pretty atypical, too.  You'd typically want to limit setter/getter to things that can be expressed with `@property`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest to (possibly) use ARC, and if you can't use it (or maybe you just want to understand how memory management works?), to don't send retain and release messages from outside the class. Instead you should do this in the accessors.

So you should create a retain or copy property (usually with immutable strings is preferable to use copy, because they may be assigned to mutable strings, so making invalid the assumption that you are working with an immutable - thus thread safe - property).

So in your case I suggest a setter like this one:

```
- (void) setToolName: (NSString*) toolName
{
    if(_toolName== toolName)
        return;
    [_toolName release];
    _toolName= [toolName copy];
}
```

This way you're doing it fine, you shouldn't be concerned about what is the retain count of the setter argument. In case it is a string literal which has an unknown retain count, the object does not even respond to a release message, so it will stay alive for all the program (unlike it seems it is efficient because it avoids the overhead of creating an object at runtime). If you copy an immutable object (unless it something like a cached *NSNumber*, or a string literal), the code just does a simple assignment and the retain count gets increased.

So if you just follow the rule of "I retain (or copy) what I need to use, I release what I don't need to use anymore", you're doing it fine and you shouldn't worry about what happens in particular case like with string literals.

Comment: However, if you are going to use a setter like that one, you are far better off using `@property(copy) NSString *toolName;` and letting the compiler synthesize the setter/getter and ivar automatically.

Comment: Yes, sure this is just to illustrate the concept.